# ISPConfig 3, configuring subdomains for one domain

Tags: debian, subdomain, server-administration

I have a problem with configuring subdomains on ISPConfig 3.
I have server with installed Debian, Nginx, PHP-FPM, MySQL and ISPConfig. I have a task to configure ISPConfig in such way:

1. Create single domain for whole server.
2. Create some users
3. Allow them to create subdomains for main server domain(something like service address, it's nedded for creating sites withoutbying new domain for each task and programmer), which is under control of server admin. They must have ability to create subdomains(with FTP, MySQL etc) for domain themselves, without external help.

How can be done this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a server with IP 12.34.56.78 and you own a domain, say example.com and you want your server be called "hello". First you have to log as root and

   ```
   echo "hello" > /etc/hostname
   hostname -F /etc/hostname
   ```

Now you just asigned you domain to your server, now it is called hello.example.com.This is not an ispconfig issue.

For you questions 2 and 3 take a look at http://docs.ispconfig.org/. They explain how to create users and config their ftp accounts.